# Qual a extensão do VisualG para o GitHub?

Tags: github, visualg

Tenho uns códigos meus antigos em VisualG e gostaria de publicar no GitHub, alguém sabe a extensão do VisualG que o GitHub reconhece?

Comment: Provavelmente nenhuma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O GitHub não reconhece os códigos do VisualG.

Quando alguém opta por colocar códigos do VisualG no GitHub essas pessoas normalmente o disponibiliza em formato txt.

Answer (score 0):

O VisualG salva os seus scripts com a extensão `.por` que *acho* que também é usada pelo [Portugol Studio](http://lite.acad.univali.br/portugol/), porém, mesmo se você enviar seus arquivos com esta extensão, creio que ela não será reconhecida pelo `GitHub` pois de fato não é uma linguagem.

Veja => [Pseudocódigo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoc%C3%B3digo)